# Unit test which requires a file in Request.Files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, unit-testing

I'm writing a unit test and the piece of code its testing requires that a file be in Request.Files.

In my controller I'm calling something called `AddDocument(file)` and the file is taken from Request.Files.

How do you achieve unit testing this? Isn't the Request only available in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out [this blog by scott hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx) on the topic.  its pretty informative and well written.